# Chinese cartoon movie with monkey-like child, mother taken away, bad uncle?

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, cartoon

I have small flashes of a cartoon, anime or something of the sort, my father bought it from a Chinese boutique when I was very very young.

The small number of details I remember is the boy's going by the name of Chincha or Xhincha (in voice input Jiānqiáng), his mother is taken away by his uncle or so I think, he grows up, he has a spear and a tail maybe comes back to fight his uncle.

I do believe there is presence of monkeys but I can't quite place it, (maybe raised by monkeys).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Lotus Lantern* (1999)?

From [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/lotus_lantern_bao_lian_deng):

> Sanshengmu is a goddess who falls in love with a mortal man and leaves the heavens for earth with her magical lotus lantern in tow. **Several years later, Sanshengmu's older brother Er Lang, still furious at his sister's impropriety, finds her, captures her, and hides her deep inside Mt. Hua.** But Sanshengmu now has a young son, and when he discovers what has happened to his mother, he sets out to find the Monkey King, whose magical powers could set Sanshengmu free. **But will the young boy prove worthy in the eyes of the Monkey King?**

If I believe [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_Lantern) the boy's name is Chenxiang, which matches your phonetic recollection.

---

Found with the Google query `chinese animated movie uncle monkey site:en.wikipedia.org`.

Comment: As soon as I saw the poster I started imploding with emotions, thousand thanks brother !